# How can I get a CSS table DIV to be constrained inside another DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have an outer DIV as follows. When I check in the browser the outer DIV given the class `colx2-right` is the correct size of almost half of the area it's inside of.

```
.colx2-right {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 48%;
}
```

Inside of the above DIV I have a CSS table defined with:

```
div.container {
    display: table;
}
```

If there is a lot of data in one of the columns then text overflows the edges of the `colx2-right` DIV. Is there some way I could get it to stay within the boundry of the `colx2-right` DIV?

I created a fiddle that shows the problem. Here you can see the color of the yellow and red backgrounds is just less than 50% but the red background does not constrain the table inside of it.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cK48u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say setting a width 100% on the div.container should make it work the way you want.

If that is not the case, I am probably not understanding your question correctly. It would help if you tossed an example in http://www.jsfiddle.net so there can be no confusion.

Another thought (though i've never used display: table on a div): since you used display: table, we might asume the div is in fact a table. That would also mean the table-layout properties apply.

Try setting `table-layout:fixed;` and setting the 100% width.

Comment: I tried width: 100% as an inline style but it did nothing. Seems like the inside DIV stretched as much as it wanted and took no account of the outer DIV. I am wondering if this is because I am using CSS tables (display: table).

Comment: Well put your code up on jsfiddle. That way people can take a look at exactly what you have and try to fix it online.

Comment: Is it okay to use table-layout: fixed when I am using CSS tables? Hope the fiddle I uploaded better shows my problem. I did try table-layout and this does work for the table itself but then the text inside the right hand cells goes outside of the boundry of the table.

Comment: Thats because you have `white-space: nowrap;`. Fixed in fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cK48u/1/